# Django asking for instance instead of value

Tags: django

I have a django app with these models (only relevant fields):

```
class Device(models.Model):
    serial = models.PositivewSmallIntegerField(unique=True, defeult=0000)
….

class Conexion(models.Model):
    serial = models.ForeignKey(Device, to_field='serial', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

….

When I try to assign a integer value to serial in Conexión, django asks for a Device instance. But this is wrong, because I have set to_field='serial'. I have exactly the same Foreign key in another model and it works ok.

This is the exception:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "11": "Conexión.serial" must be a "Device" instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django always makes two "twin" fields in case of a `field = ForeignKey(..)`:

1. a `field` that acts as a lazy getter and setter for *objects* to which field points (so in this case `Device`s, not their "*unique identifier*"); and
2. a `field_id` that has the value stored in the foreign key field.

You thus should here assign to the `field_id`, like:

```
Conexion(serial_id=11)
```

Comment: I downvoted your answer by mistake. If you edit it, s.o. will let me fix my error